# How do I group a MySQL query by two different columns?

Tags: mysql, group-by

The question I am working on is:

> Provide the average answer for questions in broken down by Province and then by Question.  You must include the province and the question as well as the average.

The example output is meant to look something like this:

```
 Ontario - Do you like blak? - 3.4
 Ontario - Do you like flah? - 2.3
 Ontario - Do you like rahhggg? - 4.8
 Alberta - Do you like flah? - 2.3
 Alberta - Do you like rahhggg? - 4.8
```

So far I have tried to list them by question with the average but I don't know how to group it by the province first. I think it's a JOIN but I'm not sure how to lay it out. What I have:

```
SELECT survey_question_id, AVG(survey_response)
FROM survey_responses
JOIN survey_responders 
ON survey_responses.id = survey_responders.id
WHERE survey_responders.province='Ontario'
GROUP BY survey_question_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT province,survey_question_id, AVG(survey_response)
FROM survey_responses
JOIN survey_responders 
ON survey_responses.id = survey_responders.id
WHERE survey_responders.province='Ontario'
GROUP BY province,survey_question_id;
```

if you need all the provinces just remove the `Where` like this

```
SELECT province,survey_question_id, AVG(survey_response)
FROM survey_responses
JOIN survey_responders 
ON survey_responses.id = survey_responders.id
GROUP BY province,survey_question_id;
```

Comment: You need to add `province` into the select clause as well.

Comment: I have to group the provinces as if there are many different places. Does this solution only do Ontario?

Comment: Yes, but then you only need to remove the `WHERE survey_responders.province='Ontario'` clause

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY statement within MySQL determines how the query engine aggregates the data. You are currently grouping only by survey_question_id. since the ids will all be different, you will never get a aggregate in your results.

I would suggest changing your group by to:

```
GROUP BY survey_responders.province, survey_responses.questiontitle
```

and make sure you edit your SELECT statement appropriately.